# Center a table in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How can you center an entire table in Internet Explorer 7+?

I want to avoid on centering the `<td>` element. I want to center the entire table with `width:auto;`nearly 1050 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

`text-align: center;` on the body element should do it **if the document is in quirks mode**, otherwise the usual way of centering will also work even without a width on a table `margin: 0 auto`

added:

here's a link to a previous answer on the subject, covers both quirks and standards

[CSS way to horizontally align table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301147/css-way-to-horizontally-align-table/301164#301164)

Comment: It *shouldn't*, but will if IE is in Quirks mode (which you should ensure it is not)

Comment: thx, David  a bit quick lol -  I was adding more info as you spoke, I agree docs shouldn't be in quirks but sometimes people have to work with legacy code still

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` to center.

This should be fine in IE7 although I don't have it to test with.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Lyz9n/)

Comment: @Town This code will not work there because i am using asp.net and ajax controls in it

Comment: @Subodh Bansal: Take the rendered HTML and post that.

Comment: @Subodh Bansal: In that case just post the code in your question so people can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a Doctype that triggers standards mode, then set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on the table. Further reading: [Centring using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/)

Comment: All else being equal, it should do. we can't tell why it doesn't without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog post you should be able to use CSS,  http://csssky.blogspot.com/2007/04/to-center-table-using-css-only.html

> table {
>   margin-left : auto;
>   margin-right : auto;
>   }

However, there seems to be an issue with IE 7 that they recommend adding the following to the beginning of the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
```