# Change color of div with javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a div with some text, I want to change its background color on "onmouseover" event, its working fine in Internet Explorer but not working at all in Firefox.

Please answer.

Every attempt would be respected.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what have you tried? and your question says it's working in Firefox, but not Firfox???

Comment: It works fine in firefox but doesn't work at all in firefox?? Please show us the code you are using.

Comment: please post your source code here so more optimal solution you will get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a Pure javascript solution for your problem tell if it works for you

```
<div onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#CCFF99';"
onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';" ">

Hello Welcome Testing Bg color on MouseOver 
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/577nc/1)

jsfiddle.net/577nc/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, please try answer this thread also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920979/center-a-table-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in firefox:

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #div_to_change_colour {
                background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeColor(objectPassedIn){
                objectPassedIn.style.background = '#CCC';
                objectPassedIn.style.width = '200px';
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div_to_change_colour" onmouseover="changeColor(this)">
            text inside div
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem you may have been facing is if you set the divs background color with 'background-color'. The above code uses 'background' to set the divs color and this can then be overided with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

> want to change its background color on
>   "onmouseover" event

also you can make it using the simple **CSS** without any javascript code:

```
.myDiv {
 background:#ffffff;
}
.myDiv:hover {
  background:#cccccc;
}
```