# Display HTML table in center of screen

Tags: php, html, css

Having problems with elegantly showing this table in the center of the screen. Please advice?

The web link is pasted below:

http://www.technicaldebt.co.uk/fyp/prototype/databasetest.php

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<table border="5" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Title</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">First Name</font></td> 
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Last Name</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">E-mail Address</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Project Title</font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Titles");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"FirstName");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"LastName");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"Email");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"ProjectRoles");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301147/css-way-to-horizontally-align-table

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typo or not but you're missing you </table> tag, which can mess up your rendering.

Comment: You should post the generated html as this is not related to php.

Comment: Thanks, added the </table> tag and the rending is still messed up ;x

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="margin: 0 auto"` within table start tag

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically an answer, but I guess (?) I'm too junior to write comments instead of "answer"s...

- At least in the question, you're still missing `</table>`
- @jeroen is talking CSS - that goes in `<style type="text/css">css here</style>` in `<head>`, or in one of your external style sheets.
- While you're at it, you can trim out the repeated `<font>` tags with the CSS

  `td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}`
- Anyone who looks at your link now has email addresses for several members of the technical debt team.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
table {
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 80%;    // or whatever you like
}
```