# How to horizontally align css table elements?

Tags: html, css

Trying to replicate this sort of design/structure: 
**Notice Below the two boxes on one side of the table and the one big one on the other!**
[image]
How would I achieve this using table css? Here's my current code, which is vertically stacked:

```
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailContainer">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="emailHeader">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                This is where my body content goes.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="emailBody">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                This is where my body content goes.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="emailFooter">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                This is where my body content goes.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Any idea?:

Comment: see my answer! i tried my best!

Comment: Look into using flex design. It will do what you need with considerably less code.

Comment: Can you accept my answer if you thaught it was good?

Comment: You are using obsolete attributes. `align` and `valign`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Steven is right, in [theory](http://theodorakis.net/tablecentertest.html):

> the “correct” way to center a table using CSS. Conforming browsers ought to center tables if the left and right margins are equal. The simplest way to accomplish this is to set the left and right margins to “auto.” Thus, one might write in a style sheet:

```
  table
 { 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

But the article mentioned in the beginning of this answer gives you all the other way to center a table.

An elegant css cross-browser solution: 
This works in both MSIE 6 (Quirks and Standards), Mozilla, Opera and even Netscape 4.x without setting any explicit widths:

```
  div.centered 
{
    text-align: center;
}

   div.centered table 
 {
     margin: 0 auto; 
     text-align: left;
 }


   <div class="centered">
    <table>
    …
    </table>
 </div>
```

## See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301164/8749048)

**edit thats center this is horizontal just change the neccecery css or see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_align)!**

Comment: Why are you shouting at us in large bold text?

Comment: Im not. sorry ill remove bold but  it was to make it stand out